# How to Fetch an excel File from an API in Android

Tags: android, excel, file, kotlin, bytestream

I have a task to fetch an excel file from an endpoint and display it on the android app. When I ran the endpoint with Postman, I got a response of this nature:

`PK`
`����`

I have not done something of this before. Please can someone explain the data type of those symbols and what I am supposed to handle it on the application using Kotlin or java.

Please help

Comment: Start bytes of a zip file?

Comment: If your question is about Postman then you are on the wrong forum.

Comment: Further, talking about an endpoint is very vague. If your file is on a server somewhere than show how its url would look like. And downloading a file is downloading a file. Type does not matter if done well.

Comment: @blackapps It's not a zip file. It's an excel file that was converted into byteStream and passed through an endpoint